# DialogViewController breaks UINavigationController path

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I encountered a problem when pushing a `DialogViewController` to my apps global `UINavigationController`, that it would lose the back buttons.

I was able to boil it down to this simple example:

```
var nav = new UINavigationController();
window.RootViewController = nav;

nav.PushViewController(new UIViewController() { Title = "#1"}, true);
nav.PushViewController(new DialogViewController(new RootElement("#2")), true);
nav.PushViewController(new UIViewController() { Title = "#3"}, true);
```

You can get from `#3` to `#2`, but not from `#2` to `#1`.

Am I doing something wrong with the `DialogViewController`? I though they could work as a drop-in replacement for `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use:

```
nav.PushViewController(new DialogViewController(new RootElement("#2"), true), true);
```

i.e. extra `true` for the `DialogViewControler` constructor.

Comment: That was tricky. But I assume there are good reasons behind straying away from the default behavior of UIViewController.

Comment: This has been stumping me for a while.  I would love to know how you found that out...

Comment: @ChristianPayne I don't exactly recall how I found that out - but it was likely be reading the MT.D's source code, which is available on https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog